# Trying to convert german format of variable into international, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The script i use gets content from an HTML element, which is in German decimal format (1380,20), and sets this as variable.

I'm trying to convert this number into the standard international decimal format (1380.20), so that the script can use it for calculations. But it doesn't work - i'm getting the result "NaN".

Since i'm a javascript beginner, i'm probably doing it wrong. But i lack the knowledge to find the error. Researched for almost two hours about this particular method, but can't puzzle it out. :(

```
var euroTotal = $('.euroTotal').toLocaleString('en-US');
```

Any helpful pointers what's wrong with this?

Comment: 1) `$('.euroTotal')` returns a jQuery object, you probably meant `$('.euroTotal').text()`. 2) You'll need to parse the text as a number before formatting it with `toLocaleString()`. See the duplicate for hints

Comment: (1) Yes, i meant $('.euroTotal').text(). (2) Oh, i think i now vaguely understand the problem. I will look into the linked thread for how to parse as a number. Thank you very much for the quick response.